# Finding first call for a case in last 7 days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a scenario where there are cases and multiple calls are made to customers against those cases. All these call logs are in a table which has following columns -

```
id primary key int
case_id int
call_made_at timestamp
```

I have to find number of new calls(1st call made for any case) made in last 7 days and number of old calls (any call which is not 1st call for any case) in last 7 days.

I can use row_number() with partition over case_id. But lifetime of case id is not much. So doing a partition on the entire table seems bad. Also table will soon become huge.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I see this as aggregation, not window functions:

```
select sum(case when min_cma >= current_date - interval '7 day' then 1 else 0 end) as last_7_days,
       sum(case when max_cma >= current_date - interval '7 day' and
                     min_cms < current_date - interval '7 day' 
                then 1 else 0 end) as 
from (select cl.case_id,
             min(call_made_at) as min_cma,
             max(call_made_at) as max_cma
      from call_logs cl
      group by cl.case_id
     ) cl;
```

You can add something like `where max_cma >= current_date - interval '7 day'` to the outer query.  It will probably improve performance.

Comment: I am not sure how will this count all new and old calls made in last 7 days.

Comment: @SiddharthPrakashSingh . . . This counts the number of cases where the first call was made in the last 7 days.  That appears to be what you are asking for (for the first column).

Comment: I wanted to get number of new calls and number of old calls made in last 7 days.